# count to return 0 if no records founds

Tags: mysql

I have a set of tables that keep the daily information of the registrations. Now I need a query in MySQL that contains total records by current date. I made a query that works fine, but I expected 0 (zero) on the computers that have not registered any records. Here it does not return 0.

I tried IFNULL () and COALESCE () but I still get the same result. Please help with this query. Thanks.......

```
SELECT e.Equipo, COUNT(ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle) as captura  
FROM equipos as e 
LEFT JOIN equipos_detalle as eq
 ON e.ID_Equipo = eq.ID_Equipo
LEFT JOIN elecciones_contactos as ec
 on ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle = eq.ID_Equipos_Detalle
WHERE ec.FechaAlta BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + 1
GROUP by ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle
```

| ID_Equipos | Equipos |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Zona 1 |
| 2 | Zona 2 |
| 3 | Zona 3 |
| 4 | Zona 4 |
| 5 | Zona 5 |
| 6 | Zona 6 |
| 7 | Zona 7 |
| 8 | Zona 8 |

| ID_Equipos_Detalle | ID_Equipos | ID_Responsable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 152 |
| 2 | 2 | 158 |
| 3 | 3 | 156 |
| 4 | 4 | 156 |
| 5 | 5 | 176 |
| 6 | 6 | 178 |
| 7 | 7 | 167 |
| 8 | 8 | 172 |

| ID_Contactos | ID_Equipos_Detalle | Contacto | Fecha_Alta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jorge | 2021-04-26 12:20:27 |
| 2 | 2 | Pedro | 2021-04-26 11:30:25 |
| 3 | 3 | Fernando | 2021-04-26 11:20:23 |
| 4 | 4 | Felipe | 2021-04-26 10:22:27 |
| 5 | 5 | Luis | 2021-04-25 10:22:27 |
| 6 | 6 | Alexis | 2021-04-25 10:12:30 |
| 7 | 7 | Victor | 2021-04-24 09:22:28 |
| 8 | 8 | Cesar | 2021-04-24 09:15:27 |

Got Result:

| Equipos | captura |
| --- | --- |
| Zona 1 | 1 |
| Zona 2 | 2 |
| Zona 5 | 1 |

Expected result (where the date is 2021 - 04 - 26):

| Equipos | captura |
| --- | --- |
| Zona 1 | 1 |
| Zona 2 | 2 |
| Zona 3 | 0 |
| Zona 4 | 0 |
| Zona 5 | 1 |
| Zona 6 | 0 |
| Zona 7 | 0 |
| Zona 8 | 0 |

Comment: You are re-declaring `e` --> `FROM equipos as e  LEFT JOIN equipos_detalle as e`  Is this intentional?

Comment: No @Zak, I already corrected

Comment: Have you tried grouping by with ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle and ec.FechaAlta both?

Comment: yes, i tried @RohitMittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering out rows that don't have any records for the given date. Just move the filtering into the LEFT JOIN part.

So instead of

```sql
LEFT JOIN elecciones_contactos as ec
 on ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle = eq.ID_Equipos_Detalle
WHERE ec.FechaAlta BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + 1
GROUP by ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle
```

do this

```sql
LEFT JOIN elecciones_contactos as ec
 on ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle = eq.ID_Equipos_Detalle
   and ec.FechaAlta BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + 1
GROUP by e.ID_Equipos
```

Also notice that I have moved the group by from `ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle` to `e.ID_Equipos`

Here is a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wgjZS5YzHanusEGvAkvU8o/0) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE is discarding rows, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT e.Equipo, COUNT(ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle) AS captura  
FROM equipos AS e 
LEFT JOIN equipos_detalle AS eq ON e.ID_Equipo = eq.ID_Equipo
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM elecciones_contactos WHERE FechaAlta BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS ec ON ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle = eq.ID_Equipos_Detalle
GROUP by ec.ID_Equipo_Detalle
```

Some column names in your query don't match them in your tables (ID_Equipo in your query is ID_Equipos in your table).